# After Hours Q/A

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics

Do questions answered tale off after 5PM EST?

I would love to see some statistics on the traffic on SO as the East Coast logs off and heads home.

Comment: You have 7k rep, you should know about meta already.

Comment: keep on truckin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the per-hour question graph from the latest data dump. ([More statistics available](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html).)

As you might imagine, the world is a lot bigger than Eastern Standard Time.

[image: questions by hour]

Comment: fantastic ! ! !

Comment: Wow those statistics are amazing! Thanks for pointing/creating them!

Comment: If you like those, there are [lots more statistics for each site](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/), too.

Comment: @GregHewgill: The [link](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html) you posted in answer is disabled. Do you have a new link address?

Comment: @AugustoVasques: I'm afraid I don't have those stats online any longer (a few server moves later, they just got lost). [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) is a better way to get those stats now. For example, https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1753452/post-volume-per-hour-of-day-day-of-week#graph shows pretty much the same results as above.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could probably query https://data.stackexchange.com/ to figure this out. The [query page](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) seems to contain Date objects for various actions.

Comment: I would probably need to know IP Addresses for questions with accepted answers.

Comment: Questions have IP addresses? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I guess @hunter is looking for a way to filter on region/timezone. IP addresses are not available in the data dumps though. Might be a nice enhancement though, to add some not-too-private region to the user details.